# Extending python dictionary and changing key values

Tags: python

Assume I have a python dictionary with 2 keys.

```
dic = {0:'Hi!', 1:'Hello!'}
```

What I want to do is to extend this dictionary by duplicating itself, but change the key value.
For example, if I have a code

```
dic = {0:'Hi!', 1:'Hello'}
multiplier = 3
def DictionaryExtend(number_of_multiplier, dictionary):
    "Function code"
```

then the result should look like

```
>>> DictionaryExtend(multiplier, dic)
>>> dic
>>> dic = {0:'Hi!', 1:'Hello', 2:'Hi!', 3:'Hello', 4:'Hi!', 5:'Hello'}
```

In this case, I changed the key values by adding the multipler at each duplication step. What's the efficient way of doing this?

Plus, I'm also planning to do the same job for list variable. I mean, extend a list by duplicating itself and change some values like above exmple. Any suggestion for this would be helpful, too!

Comment: If the keys are always going to be a consecutive range of integers starting at 0, then this dict should probably be a list. If the keys *aren't* always going to be that, then you're going to have to elaborate on how you want this dict "extended".

Comment: @user2357112 The key values for initial dictionary are ascending order starting from 0

Comment: Why are you calling that variable `multiplier` when you're adding it? That's only going to be confusing.

Comment: @kindall I have to decide the size of extended dictionary, so that information is needed

Comment: But why are you calling it `multiplier` when you're not using it to multiply anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `itertools` to repeat the values and `OrderedDict` to maintain input order.

```
import itertools as it
import collections as ct


def extend_dict(multiplier, dict_):
    """Return a dictionary of repeated values."""
    return dict(enumerate(it.chain(*it.repeat(dict_.values(), multiplier))))

d = ct.OrderedDict({0:'Hi!', 1:'Hello!'})
multiplier = 3
extend_dict(multiplier, d)
# {0: 'Hi!', 1: 'Hello!', 2: 'Hi!', 3: 'Hello!', 4: 'Hi!', 5: 'Hello!'}
```

---

Regarding handling other collection types, it is not clear what output is desired, but the following modification reproduces the latter and works for lists as well:

```
def extend_collection(multiplier, iterable):
    """Return a collection of repeated values."""
    repeat_values = lambda x: it.chain(*it.repeat(x, multiplier))
    try:
        iterable = iterable.values()
    except AttributeError:
        result = list(repeat_values(iterable))
    else:
        result = dict(enumerate(repeat_values(iterable)))
    return result

lst = ['Hi!', 'Hello!']
multiplier = 3
extend_collection(multiplier, lst)
# ['Hi!', 'Hello!', 'Hi!', 'Hello!', 'Hi!', 'Hello!']
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not immediately clear why you might want to do this. If the keys are always consecutive integers then you probably just want a list.

Anyway, here's a snippet:

```
def dictExtender(multiplier, d):
    return dict(zip(range(multiplier * len(d)), list(d.values()) * multiplier))
```

Comment: I make this dictionary by reading a file line by line, and it is not orgarnized in ascending order. For example, the first line is 1:'Hello!', and the second line is 0:'Hi. and I append each line to a list, the order will be broken. So I thought that making dictionary is efficient

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use inheritance to achieve that. It's also unclear what the keys should be in the resulting dictionary.

If the keys are always consecutive integers, then why not use a list?

```
origin = ['Hi', 'Hello']
extended = origin * 3 
extended
>> ['Hi', 'Hello', 'Hi', 'Hello', 'Hi', 'Hello']
extended[4]
>> 'Hi'
```

If you want to perform a different operation with the keys, then simply:

```
mult_key = lambda key: [key,key+2,key+4] # just an example, this can be any custom implementation but beware of duplicate keys
dic = {0:'Hi', 1:'Hello'}
extended = { mkey:dic[key] for key in dic for mkey in mult_key(key) }
extended
>> {0:'Hi', 1:'Hello', 2:'Hi', 3:'Hello', 4:'Hi', 5:'Hello'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to extend anything, you need to pick a better input format or a more appropriate type.

As others have mentioned, you need a list, not an extended dict or OrderedDict. Here's an example with `lines.txt`:

```
1:Hello!
0: Hi.
2: pylang
```

And here's a way to parse the lines in the correct order:

```
def extract_number_and_text(line):
    number, text = line.split(':')
    return (int(number), text.strip())

with open('lines.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    data = [extract_number_and_text(line) for line in lines]
    print(data)
    # [(1, 'Hello!'), (0, 'Hi.'), (2, 'pylang')]
    sorted_text = [text for i,text in sorted(data)]
    print(sorted_text)
    # ['Hi.', 'Hello!', 'pylang']
    print(sorted_text * 2)
    # ['Hi.', 'Hello!', 'pylang', 'Hi.', 'Hello!', 'pylang']
    print(list(enumerate(sorted_text * 2)))
    # [(0, 'Hi.'), (1, 'Hello!'), (2, 'pylang'), (3, 'Hi.'), (4, 'Hello!'), (5, 'pylang')]
```